# How to prove ceiling and floor inequality more 'formally'?

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing, ceiling-and-floor-functions

The inequality in question is below:

$x - 1 < \lfloor x\rfloor \le x \le \lceil x \rceil < x + 1 $

Essentially, I must prove the above for every real number $x$. To begin this proof, I broke it into two cases: $x$ is an integer or $x$ is a real number.

**Case 1 ($x$ is an integer):**

I break this part up into two components to prove the left and the right side of the inequality.

For the left component,

For $x - 1 < \lfloor x\rfloor \le x$, we know that $\lfloor x\rfloor = x$ since $ x \in \mathbb Z$ therefore $ x - 1 < x \le x$ holds.

For the right component,

For $x \le \lceil x \rceil \le x + 1$, we know that $\lceil x \rceil = x$ since $ x \in \mathbb Z$ therefore $x \le \lceil x \rceil \le x + 1$ holds.

**Case 2 ($x$ is a real number and non-integer):**

Here is the part where I have trouble proving 'formally'.

For the left component,

For $x - 1 < \lfloor x\rfloor \le x$, we know that if $x = 4.5$ we know that $\lfloor x\rfloor = 4$, which is greater than $ x - 1 = 3.5 $. So, we know that $x - 1 < \lfloor x\rfloor \le x$ holds. This works for all $ x \in \mathbb {R} $.

For the right component,

For $x \le \lceil x \rceil \le x + 1$, we know that if $x = 4.5$ we know that $\lfloor x\rfloor = 5$, which is greater than $ x $. We know that $x + 1 > 5$, so $x \le \lceil x \rceil \le x + 1$ holds. This works for all $ x \in \mathbb {R} $.

Since both the left and the right components of the inequality hold, the whole inequality holds.

I am new to proofs, so I'm not sure if I'm doing this proof by induction or deduction (or something). All I know is that I was able to construct cases in which I know that this inequality works. However, I do not feel that my proof is 'all there'. I feel that Case 1 is sound enough to be considered a proof, but I feel my Case 2 is lacking. Is there any way I can prove this more formally if the above work is unacceptable as a proof?

**EDIT:**

Adding proof to show that the inequality holds:

The floor is defined as $\lfloor x \rfloor = n \le x < n + 1$.

If $x$ is a real number and $n$ is an integer, then $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is defined as the smallest integer less than or equal to $x$. (Credit to kccu) Since the smallest integer would be equivalent to $x$, we know that $x - 1 < \lfloor x \rfloor$ is less than $x$. Therefore, the left hand side of the inequality $x - 1 < \lfloor x\rfloor \le x$ holds.

Since $\lceil x \rceil$ is defined to be the smallest integer that is greater than or equal to $x$, $n + 1$ is an integer greater than or equal to $x$. Since $n$ is not $/re x$, we know that $n + 1$ is the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$ (Again, credit to kccu). Since we know that $n + 1$ is the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$, the right hand side of the equation holds since $\lceil x \rceil$ is equivalent to x since it is the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$. Thus, the right hand side holds as well.

Comment: If $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$, then there exists some integer $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n<x<n+1$. Now write $\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $\lceil x \rceil$ in terms of $n$.

Comment: Would saying $x \notin \mathbb {Z}$ be proof by contradiction?

Comment: No, I'm just starting at Case 2 because that is the case you said you had a problem with. Case 1 is just fine the way it is.

Comment: Ah, I see. For the left component of the inequality involving the floor, $\lfloor x \rfloor = n \le x < n + 1 $. The right component of the inequality is defined in terms of $n$ as $\lceil x \rceil = n < x \le n + 1 $.

Comment: Almost... the ceiling should be $\lceil x \rceil = n+1$.

Comment: I see, since the ceiling is always $x + 1$. In order to continue the second case of the proof, do I substitute these definitions into the inequality? EDIT: Well, for the left component I could say something along the lines that the floor must be higher than $n - 1$ since it must be equal to $n$ or less than $n + 1$., therefore the left side holds. However, this does not seem so formal..

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the ceiling is always $x+1$." If $n$ is an integer and $x$ is a real number such that $n<x<n+1$, then $\lceil x \rceil$ is defined to be the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$ - which is $n+1$. To prove that the inequality holds, show that $n=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $n+1=\lceil x \rceil$ satisfy it.

Comment: If you can show `Ceiling[x]-Floor[x] = 1`, the rest of the proof should follow easily.

Comment: Quick update, I added your suggestion to the post @kccu. I'm still working on showing that $n + 1 = \lceil x \rceil$.

Comment: $\lceil x \rceil$ is defined to be the _smallest_ integer that is greater than or equal to $x$. $n+1$ is an integer greater than or equal to $x$. Is it the smallest? Well check out the next smallest integer, which is $n$. Is $n \geq x$? No, because $n<x$. So $n+1$ is in fact the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$.

Comment: I made an error in the original inequality, the right hand side should be $x \le \lceil x \rceil < x + 1$. However, I also updated the proof steps you suggested to reflect that.

Comment: The tag ([tag:proof-theory]) is intended for questions about proof theory as a branch of mathematical logic, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-theory/info) and relevant [discussion on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11195/the-proof-theory-tag-is-misused-too-often). It is not intended for all questions related to proofs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all depends on your definition of the Floor and Ceiling functions... once you choose a definition you can show the different forms are synonymous, but you must choose a definition. Perhaps the easiest definition I have seen for you purposes comes from Wikipedia

> Since there is exactly one integer in a half-open interval of length one, for any real x there are unique integers m and n satisfying $x-1 < m \leq x \leq n < x+1$

From this we can define $\lfloor x \rfloor = m$ and $\lceil x \rceil = n$ and your proof becomes trivial... a self evidence by a substitution

Comment: So does this mean the proof is satisfied because m is some integer less than or equal to x but greater than x - 1 (for the left side of the inequality, same logic on the right)? Or is there more to it than that?

Comment: @TheLongDark this proof works because this is how we define the floor function.... There is always a unique m and n for any given x satisfying the property above.... Think about it?, either your interval of 1 goes from say, 2.5-3.5 and only crosses 3 or it goes from 3-4, but is only either 3 *or* 4 since once side of the interval is open (the choice of the side you leave open is irrelevant), and we define m as the floor and n as the ceiling. Then, just plug in $m=\lfloor x \rfloor$ and $n = \lceil x \rceil$

Comment: @TheLongDark remember that a half open set is something like $(0,1]$ where one endpoint is included but the other is not.... A fundamental property of real numbers says only integer lies in any half open interval of length 1. We define the closed side of one interval to be $x$ in our proof and the open side to be x-1, giving an interval of length one.... Thus some integer m must exist.. Do the same for n

Comment: If you define the floor as the greatest integer less than or equal to x and the ceiling the smallest integer greater than or equal than x all you have to do is note that the m and n satisfied by my definition are unique and are the first integers encountered on either side except for maybe x itself.... The equivalance is therefore shown

Comment: you could first express everything in terms of some mathematical logic and show the equivalance, but this isn't really any more formal since we defined the floor and ceiling that way.. All that you depend on is the construction of the real numbers

Comment: So defining both the floor and ceiling functions satisfies the proof as long as I show that they are satisfied by your definition? Sorry, this is my first proof. I think I understand the interval you suggested - $x $represents the closed side of the interval, which is our integer. The open end of the interval corresponds to $x-1$, which allows some real number to exist within the interval. But because of the way we defined the floor and ceiling function, the inequality holds since it will never be less than $x-1$ on the left and never greater than $x+1$ on the right?

Comment: @TheLongDark exactly. Really what I show is backwards from the standard proof you see in that I first define the floor and ceiling in terms of your inequality solution and then work backwards to show that this definition is synonymous with the common one, but that doesn't make it any less rigid.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped a lot with my understanding of this proof. If you don't mind, I have one more question - the method used to reach this proof, does it have a name? I know that there are things like proof by contradiction, generalized mathematical induction, deduction, etc... The proof book I'm reading gives things names like that.

Comment: @TheLongDark sure thing! Other than defining the formula above all we do is substitute in m and n as the floor and ceiling function (a transformation) and equality of statements. You could formally work this into a number of proof structures, although deduction is probably the closest of the ones you list... We assume A (our definition) and then imply B using known results (showing the equality of the definition I use and the common definitions of the floor and ceiling functions).

Comment: Thank you @Brevan Ellefsen! I'm going to rework this proof for practice using the method and logic you used.

Answer (score 0):

We can also define the fractional part of $x$, or $\{x\}$, to be a number between $0$ (inclusive) and $1$ (exclusive). Then, we can say $\lfloor x\rfloor = x - \{x\}$, and since $\{x\}$ is between $0$ and $1$, we have that $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is between $x-1$ and $x$. Likewise, we have $\lceil x\rceil = x + (1-\{x\})$, and $\{x\}$ is between $0$ and $1$, so $1-\{x\}$ is between $0$ and $1$, so $\lceil x\rceil$ is between $x$ and $x+1$.

Comment: It's not true that $ \lceil x \rceil = 1 - \{ x \} $. Take $ x = 0 $, where $ \lceil x \rceil = 0 $ but $ 1 - \{ x \} = 1 - 0 = 1 $.