# proof for skip list height - missing some steps?

Tags: probability, summation

The proof for the height of a Skip list is discussed at https://opendatastructures.org/ods-java/4_4_Analysis_Skiplists.html in Lemma 4.4

The proof use indicator variable ${I_r}$ as $I_r = 1$ if $L_r$ list is not empty, otherwise $0$.

I do not understand the following part:

$ = \sum_{r=1}^{\log{n}} E(I_r) + \sum_{{log(n)+1}}^{\inf} E[I_r]  $

$ = \sum_{r=1}^{\log{n}} 1 + \sum_{{\log(n)+1}}^{\inf} E[I_r]  $

why this $E(I_r)$ replaced by 1? Is this because we know there is at least one element for all lists $r \le \log(n)$?

Another confusion is, later in the proof:

$\sum_{{r = \log(n)+1}}^{\inf} \frac{n}{2^r} $

is changed to:

$ \sum_{r = 0}^{\inf} \frac{1}{2^r} $

How?

Answer (score 0):

For your first confusion, the indicator $I_r$ is never greater than $1$, therefore we can replace $E(I_r)$ by the upper bound $1$. Notice that the proof uses $\le$ at this step.

For your second confusion, the sum
$$\sum_{r=\lfloor \log n\rfloor+1}^\infty \frac n{2^r}\tag1$$
is first converted to
$$\sum_{t=0}^\infty \frac n{2^{t+\lfloor\log n\rfloor+1}}\tag2
$$ by changing the index of summation to $t:=r-(\lfloor\log n\rfloor+1)$. Factoring out a constant from (2), this equals
$$\frac n{2^{\lfloor\log n\rfloor + 1}}\sum_{t=0}^\infty\frac1{2^t}.\tag3
$$
Use [the inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1606358/215011) $\lfloor x\rfloor > x-1$ to see that $$\lfloor \log n\rfloor+1>\log n\tag4$$ which implies  $$2^{\lfloor \log n\rfloor+1}> n\tag5$$
and therefore $$\frac n{2^{\lfloor \log n\rfloor+1}}<1.\tag6$$ Putting it all together, we've shown
$$\sum_{r=\lfloor \log n\rfloor+1}^\infty \frac n{2^r}
\stackrel{(2)}=\sum_{t=0}^\infty \frac n{2^{t+\lfloor\log n\rfloor+1}}\stackrel{(3)}=\frac n{2^{\lfloor\log n\rfloor + 1}}\sum_{t=0}^\infty\frac1{2^t}\stackrel{(6)}< \sum_{t=0}^\infty\frac1{2^t}.$$